# Code assistance in PhpStorm for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-assist

I'm trying to get some code assistance going for React Native in PhpStorm.
It's working really well out of the box for all properties etc. But I would like to have code assistance help me also with the values of properties. I have added `@types/node, @types/react, @types/react-dom and @types/react-native` in *Settings>Languages & Frameworks>JavaScript>Libraries*. But still nothing.

It works good here:

[image]

But then I would also like it to assist me with the values for that property. Like in this example, it should give me 'center'.

[image]

And if I just add quotes, then a list of all available property values. Just like when you type html.

[image]

Is this at all possible for PhpStorm with React Native?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently supported. Please vote for [WEB-38735](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38735) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Ach, that sucks. But I voted there. Thank for pointing me there!